# Drupal : Single-code, Multi-site, multi-domain, multi-database. HOW?

Tags: nginx, drupal-8, multisite, multi-database, drupal-multi-domain

There are many tutorial on how to setup Drupal in different configuaration, but I can't find how to setup Multi-site, multi-domain, multi-database config with nginx and postgresql.

So far I was able to set :

1. Nginx virtual hosts (also set www.test1.com and www.test2.com in /etc/hosts for this setup)
2. Created with settings.php in :

   /var/www/drupal8/default

   /var/www/drupal8/www.test1.com

   /var/www/drupal8/www.test2.com
3. Created the default postgres DB and set up default and www.test1.com are using it.
4. Ran the install.php on the default that filled the DB.

Now the question :

If I go to : http://www.test2.com/core/install.php to set up and populate the DB for the second host, what I'm getting instead is
that "Drupal already installed" ?

How can I make test2.com use separate DB and how do I populate it ?

In general any info on Single-code, Multi-site, multi-domain, multi-database.

Answer (score 0):

Your www folders should be in the sites folder and if the folder names don't exactly match the site url, you need to set up the sites.php file.
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/multisite/multisite-drupal-8-setup